# Desktop Mail Client

Tags: c#, .net, email

Does any one know how to get Push mail notification from **Yahoo! IMAP mail server**,
Gmail IMAP server supports **IDLE command** I am using it for new mail notification AOL mail also supports IDLE command but Yahoo doesn't,
Any suggestions any help will be appreciated,
Thankx in advance

Comment: The IMAP protocol does not provide any mechanism for push notifications – IDLE is the _de facto_ standard extension for supporting such. If Yahoo! does not provide this capability (or any equivalent), then you’ll have to fall back to polling (as was intended in the original IMAP design).

Comment: I don't have an exact answer, but I know how you could find out. Both the original Yahoo Mail and the MailDroid apps for Android phones implement push functionality for Yahoo accounts. All you'd have to do is to catch and analyze the traffic at the moment the push notification arrives. Also, while the K9 Mail app doesn't support the Yahoo push method, it does provide logging, where you'll be able to see which commands are arriving. Hope this helped you some.

Comment: I suggest you to look on this blog: [Mail Client](http://abramovi.blogspot.co.il/) I believe it can help you